# How do I wake up a thread from a pool of threads waiting on condition variable/semaphore?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

Situation:

1. Thread A calls **wait**(*&sem*);     // success
2. Thread B calls **wait**(*&sem*);     // blocks
3. Thread C calls **wait**(*&sem*);     // blocks
4. Thread A calls **signal**(*&sem*);

Now what???
Which thread is awaken?

It's random right?

But, I always want Thread B to wake up before thread C because B has called wait before C. Is there an existing mechanism to do that using sync. mech.? Clearly mention use of any other data structure if needed!

Comment: None of them in the example you posted, because *Thread A calls wait(&sem);* means *Thread A calls signal(&sem);* is never reached.  If you replace *Thread A calls signal(&sem);* with *Thread D calls signal(&sem);*, any of thread A, B, or C will wake up, and in general you have no control **at all** over which one.

Comment: Initial condition : sem is initialised to 1 and thread A is the first one to get the semaphore successfully. Then why signal(&sem) will not be reached?

Comment: It will be, given your changed initial conditions.

Comment: It's part of software design to make such considerations irrelevant.  If you don't care which thread gets woken up, then you cannot be disappointed.

Comment: And if you do care which thread wakes up, then you wake up *that* thread.

Comment: Any justification as to why the question itself is downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking for something like this.
Can be implemented using condition variables to serialize the thread execution.

```
Mutex M;
Condition Variable C = 1;

thread_function_A()  
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(M);

    while (C != 1)
        pthread_cond_wait(C, M);

    CRITICAL SECTION STARTS;
    CRITICAL SECTION ENDS;
    C++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(M);
}

thread_function_B()  
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(M)

    while (C != 2)
        pthread_cond_wait(C, M);

    CRITICAL SECTION STARTS
    CRITICAL SECTION ENDS
    C++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(M)
}

thread_function_C()  
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(M)

    while (C != 3)
        pthread_cond_wait(C, M);

    CRITICAL SECTION STARTS
    CRITICAL SECTION ENDS
    C++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(M)
}
```